phonon properties
I wanted to calculate phonon properties, so I used phonopy with wien2k I followed the steps of calculating properties, step by step until I reached the step "run_lapw -fc 0.1 " I calculate the three forces then I put the three scf in the same directory everything all right after that I lunched "phonopy --wien2k -f 1.scf 2.scf 3.scf " but I encountered this error
phonopy --wien2k -f 1.scf 2.scf 3.scf
                                  2.11.0

Python version 2.7.12
Spglib version 2.0.2
Calculator interface: wien2k
Displacements were read from "phonopy_disp.yaml".
Number of files to be read (3) don't match to
the number of displacements (12) in phonopy_disp.yaml.
FORCE_SETS could not be created.

Please improve the title!

And, please upgrade to newer python versions, likely the spglib version you have installed is not compatible, or is very old.never use Python < 3.
Likely this problem will disappear when you upgrade to newer python versions.
Python 2.7 is not maintained, is dead, and is probably causing security issues for you :)

I use now the last version but the error still exist
                                  2.28.0

Compiled with OpenMP support (max 6 threads).
Python version 3.12.4
Spglib version 2.5.0
Calculator interface: wien2k
Displacements were read from "phonopy_disp.yaml".
Number of files to be read (3) don't match to
the number of displacements (12) in phonopy_disp.yaml.
FORCE_SETS could not be created.
